# Запятая перед И: "Важнее, чтобы ситуация была под контролем(,) и из-за нескольких отрицательных ответов вы не теряли заказчиков"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, придаточное-предложение

> Важнее, чтобы ситуация была под контролем и из-за нескольких отрицательных ответов в Сети вы не теряли заказчиков.

Нужна ли запятая перед "и". И почему?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна. Это однородные придаточные. У них общая часть - "важнее".